# How to drag and drop MYSQL records?

Tags: html, jquery

I know that this is probably not the right way to do this, but I this is what I have so far (I'm new to jQuery).

I have each DIV generated inside the loop depending on the number of MYSQL records.  Each div echo's the record. I need each DIV to call the draggable j Query function so that it can sit on one of the cells in the table.

The issue is that I am trying to get each div to become movable using the draggable function,  I'm not sure how to reuse the handler for each Div.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/../../../../../../../../code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  .auto-style3 {
    text-align: center;
}
  </style>
  <script src="../jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="../jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>

  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable1" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>

  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable2" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable3" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable4" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable5" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable6" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable7" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable8" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable9" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable10" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable11" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable12" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable13" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable14" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable15" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable16" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable17" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable18" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable19" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable20" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable21" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable22" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
    <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable23" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable24" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable25" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable26" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable27" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable28" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable29" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable30" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable31" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable32" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>



</head>
<body>
 
<h1 class="auto-style3"><br>Seating Planner</h1>
 
<table align="center" style="width: 676px; height: 406px">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>




    
 
 

 
 
 
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" style="width: 150px; height: 51px">
  <p> The MYSQL row will be echoed here </p>
</div>


 

    
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do realise that you don't need a script tag or ready handler for each bit of code that you have, right?

Comment: Also, if this isn't about PHP then please show the rendered html. Better yet, create a runnable snippet that illustrates your issue.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I'm not sure how to  reuse the handler for each Div.

Comment: The issue is that I am trying to get each div to become movable using the draggable function but not sure how to

Comment: Please edit your question and include the **rendered** html, not the PHP. I will then help you.

Comment: You still have php code in your question. This isn't relevant. Please remove or replace with the output of the PHP.

Comment: @LeeTaylor PHP code removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you had a few things that were wrong.

1. You don't need to create a script tag for each bit of code you write.
2. You don't need a ready handler (`'$(function() {`) for everything you do.

These first two don't cause any problems, but they are unnecessary.

3. You were under the assumption that you needed to give an id to each `div` that you wanted to be `draggable`. This is not the case, use classes instead. See `mydraggable`.
4. I assume that you want to be able to move those divs to a specific area (those tds, probably), and to prevent overlap. That's another question that you should ask separately.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".mydraggable").draggable();
});
```

```css
.mydraggable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 51px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  background: #e59959;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.auto-style3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eTyxS0rkjpLEo16uXTS0uVCS4815lc40K2iVpWDvdSY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<h1 class="auto-style3"><br>Seating Planner</h1>

<table align="center" style="width: 676px; height: 406px">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="mydraggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p> #1 The MYSQL row will be echoed here </p>
</div>
<div class="mydraggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p> #2 The MYSQL row will be echoed here </p>
</div>
<div class="mydraggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p> #3 The MYSQL row will be echoed here </p>
</div>
<div class="mydraggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p> #4 The MYSQL row will be echoed here </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, learnt a lot from this, thank you!

Comment: No problem. Please mark as answered and vote accordingly. Thanks.